# Glassfish server issue when deploying Grails application

Tags: grails, deployment, glassfish, missingmethodexception

I have an **issue when I try to deploy my web application on a GlassFish server** but I don't manage to solve it! (I don't find any useful info on Google too...).

The application has been built using the **Grails framework**.

I don't understand why the MissingMethodException is raised. To be more precise, I have only done some updates to the application that was previously installed on this server. This old application worked!

Any help would be appreciate.

Hereby the server stacktrace:

```
[#|2012-03-07T10:43:22.575+0100|WARNING|glassfishv3.0|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|StandardWrapperValve[gsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet gsp threw exception
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static Requestmap.list() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1351)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1337)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeStaticMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:934)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:35)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:121)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestmapFilterInvocationDefinitionHelper.loadRequestmaps(RequestmapFilterInvocationDefinitionHelper.groovy:50)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestmapFilterInvocationDefinition.reset(RequestmapFilterInvocationDefinition.java:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestmapFilterInvocationDefinition.initialize(RequestmapFilterInvocationDefinition.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.findConfigAttribute(AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:74)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.getAttributes(AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.java:62)
        at org.springframework.security.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:230)
        at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsAuthenticationProcessingFilter.super$3$doFilterHttp(GrailsAuthenticationProcessingFilter.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1049)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:923)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:127)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(GrailsAuthenticationProcessingFilter.groovy:56)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:65)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:66)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
|#]

[#|2012-03-07T10:43:22.583+0100|INFO|glassfishv3.0|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|PWC1412: WebModule[] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'grails-errorhandler'|#]

[#|2012-03-07T10:43:22.854+0100|WARNING|glassfishv3.0|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|ApplicationDispatcher[] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet grails-errorhandler threw exception
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.exceptions.UrlMappingException: Error mapping onto view [/error]: Cannot return Sitemesh factory it has not been set!
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet$1.doFilter(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:129)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:65)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet.doDispatch(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:664)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:499)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:364)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:475)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:669)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:364)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:329)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:334)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot return Sitemesh factory it has not been set!
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.FactoryHolder.getFactory(FactoryHolder.java:34)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet.layoutIncludedResponse(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:143)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet.access$000(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet$1.doFilter(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:126)
        ... 36 more
|#]

[#|2012-03-07T10:43:22.855+0100|WARNING|glassfishv3.0|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve@8d59eb: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=500, location=/grails-errorhandler]
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.exceptions.UrlMappingException: Error mapping onto view [/error]: Cannot return Sitemesh factory it has not been set!
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:659)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:664)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:499)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:364)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:475)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:669)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:364)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:329)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:334)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.exceptions.UrlMappingException: Error mapping onto view [/error]: Cannot return Sitemesh factory it has not been set!
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet$1.doFilter(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:129)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:65)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet.doDispatch(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot return Sitemesh factory it has not been set!
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.FactoryHolder.getFactory(FactoryHolder.java:34)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet.layoutIncludedResponse(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:143)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet.access$000(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet$1.doFilter(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:126)
        ... 36 more
----- Root Cause -----
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.exceptions.UrlMappingException: Error mapping onto view [/error]: Cannot return Sitemesh factory it has not been set!
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet$1.doFilter(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:129)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:65)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet.doDispatch(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:664)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:499)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:364)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:475)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:669)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:364)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:329)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:334)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot return Sitemesh factory it has not been set!
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.FactoryHolder.getFactory(FactoryHolder.java:34)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet.layoutIncludedResponse(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:143)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet.access$000(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet$1.doFilter(ErrorHandlingServlet.java:126)
        ... 36 more
```

Comment: what version of Grails are you using?

Comment: It's an old version of Grails, v1.2.1. However, my colleagues had already performed some updates and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I solve it!

I was developping with Eclipse using the STS IDE ([www.grails.org/STS+Integration](http://www.grails.org/STS+Integration)).

To create the WAR, we use the grails command in a terminal:

```
grails war
```

I thought grails automatically performs a clean operation before building and packaging the war. However, classes build by Eclipse remains in the WEB-INF/classes folder (see this [feed](http://markmail.org/message/wbvsupv2juichfex#query%3a+page:1+mid%3acko65kjex7brqwfl+state%3aresults)).

So, to solve this issue:

In Eclipse:

- Uncheck the "Build automatically" option
- Perform "Clean Project"

Then, in a console:

- Perform "grails clean"
- Remove any files inside the target directory

Finally, build the war with "grails war"